# NameError: name 'X_train' is not defined....tried in spyder too

Tags: python

have been trying to run this statement in colab but it's always showing the `NameError`

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(x,y,test_size = 0.33,random_state = 42)
```

pl help to solve this problem

Comment: Did you confuse `x_train` with `X_train`? The code defines `x_train`, the error says `X_train`

Comment: I agree, it appears that your error is on a different line of code from those shown. 
 The code you included initialises `x_train`, and it appears that you ***later on*** try to use `X_train`, but python is case sensitive.

Comment: actually it should be X_train at both places

Comment: I have been trying it in colab:

`from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)`

its showing 
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-931765772341> in <module>
----> 1 X_train

NameError: name 'X_train' is not defined